# Problem with the DSolve function

Tags: differential-equations

OK guys, here's the thing, Mathematica **does not return a solution** for this system of differential equations:

```
DSolve[{p11'[t] == 2*p12[t] - (1/r)*p12[t]^2, 
p12'[t] == 
p22[t] - (w^2)*p11[t] - 2*z*w*p12[t] - (1/r)*p12[t]*p22[t], 
p22'[t] == -2*(w^2)*p12[t] - 
4*z*w*p22[t] - (1/r)*p22[t]^2 + (w^4)*q, p11[0] == 0, p12[0] == 0,
p22[0] == 0}, {p11[t], p12[t], p22[t]}, t]
```

Where `z,w,r,q` are parameters.
Can anyone please try it on your system and tell me if you have the same problem?

I also tried with the `NDSolve` function

```
NDSolve[{p11'[t] == 2*p12[t] - (1/r)*p12[t]^2, 
p12'[t] == 
p22[t] - (w^2)*p11[t] - 2*z*w*p12[t] - (1/r)*p12[t]*p22[t], 
p22'[t] == -2*(w^2)*p12[t] - 
4*z*w*p22[t] - (1/r)*p22[t]^2 + (w^4)*q, p11[0] == 0, p12[0] == 0,
p22[0] == 0}, {p11[t], p12[t], p22[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

but I get the error `message:NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`

I greatly appreciate your help

(I use mathematica 8.0 and of course `VariationalMethods` is turned on)

Comment: "Mathematica does not return a solution for this system of differential equations" - this merely means that *Mathematica* **doesn't** know a lot of things, and your system of DEs is among those.

Comment: Why is it so obvious to turn on `VariationalMethods` (I guess you mean that you loaded the `VariationalMethods` package using `<<` or `Get`)? `NSolve` or `NDSolve` don't need that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using `NDSolve` all the parameters must have a numeric value.

```
solution[t_] = 
  With[{q = 1, r = 1, w = 1, z = 1}, 
   NDSolve[{p11'[t] == 2*p12[t] - (1/r)*p12[t]^2,
            p12'[t] == p22[t] - (w^2)*p11[t] - 2*z*w*p12[t] - (1/r)*p12[t] p22[t],
            p22'[t] == -2 (w^2)*p12[t] - 4*z*w*p22[t] - (1/r)*p22[t]^2 + (w^4)*q,
            p11[0] == 0,  p12[0] == 0, p22[0] == 0},
           {p11[t], p12[t], p22[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]][[1, All, 2]]

Plot[solution[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: oh wow i didn't know that, i thought it could solve using these quantities as parameters. And the command [1, All, 2] in the end, what's it about?

Comment: @LazarosM. It's to get the functions from the solution to your system of equations, given in terms of rules. If you execute the `With[...]` block alone you will see.

Comment: @LazarosM. Actually its `[[1, All, 2]]`. It's short for [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) and it's about getting the solutions in a list for plotting

Comment: Guys thank you all very much, you have been extremely helpful! and thenks for the quick immediate responses

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, here is a version with `Manipulate`. So the values of parameters can be dynamically changed:

```
Manipulate[
 solution[t_] = 
  NDSolve[{p11'[t] == 2*p12[t] - (1/r)*p12[t]^2, 
     p12'[t] == 
      p22[t] - (w^2)*p11[t] - 2*z*w*p12[t] - (1/r)*p12[t] p22[t], 
     p22'[t] == -2 (w^2)*p12[t] - 
       4*z*w*p22[t] - (1/r)*p22[t]^2 + (w^4)*q, p11[0] == 0, 
     p12[0] == 0, p22[0] == 0}, {p11[t], p12[t], p22[t]}, {t, 0, 
     10}][[1, All, 2]];

 Plot[solution[t], {t, 0, 10}]
 , {{q, 1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 , {{r, 1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 , {{w, 1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 , {{z, 1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {q, r, w, z}]
```

[image: Manipulate]