# NDSolve::dsvar error when trying to solve system of differentail equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-value

I'm currently trying to solve a set of differential equations using `NDSolve` but I'm getting an error... The following was construced with the help of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/problem-with-the-dsolve-function) answer using Mathematica 11.0.

```
solution[t_] := 
 With[{m = 0.01, L = 0.1, g = 9.81}, 
  NDSolve[{2 m (L^2 - 3 L s[t] + 3 s[t]^2) u''[t] == 
     3 L m g Sin[u[t]] + 6 m (L - 2 s[t]) s'[t] u'[t], 
    m ((L - 2 s[t]) u'[t]^2 + 2 s''[t]) == 0, u[0] == Pi, s[0] == 0, 
    s'[0] == 1, u'[0] == -0.1}, {u[t], s[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]]

Plot[solution[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

The error message is:

```
NDSolve::dsvar: 0.0002042857142857143` cannot be used as a variable.

NDSolve::dsvar: 0.0002042857142857143` cannot be used as a variable.

NDSolve::dsvar: 0.20428591836734694` cannot be used as a variable.

General::stop: Further output of NDSolve::dsvar will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

I'm not really sure what to make of the error. I found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170561/ndsolvevalue-x-cannot-be-used-as-a-variable) post here which to me at least doesn't seem related to my issue.. The initial values should work (I think at least) and I checked a couple of times now if there is any mistake in the equations...

Comment: Correct code: `solution[t_] = 
 With[{m = 0.01, L = 0.1, g = 9.81}, 
   NDSolve[{2 m (L^2 - 3 L s[t] + 3 s[t]^2) u''[t] == 
      3 L m g Sin[u[t]] + 6 m (L - 2 s[t]) s'[t] u'[t], 
     m ((L - 2 s[t]) u'[t]^2 + 2 s''[t]) == 0, u[0] == Pi, s[0] == 0, 
     s'[0] == 1, u'[0] == -0.1}, {u[t], s[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]][[1, All, 
   2]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By giving `solution` the argument `t`, what is supposed to be the variable in the iterator `{t, 0, 10}` has a numeric value when `solution[t]` is called.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

solution = 
  With[{m = 0.01, L = 0.1, g = 9.81}, 
   NDSolve[{2 m (L^2 - 3 L s[t] + 3 s[t]^2) u''[t] == 
      3 L m g Sin[u[t]] + 6 m (L - 2 s[t]) s'[t] u'[t], 
     m ((L - 2 s[t]) u'[t]^2 + 2 s''[t]) == 0, u[0] == Pi, s[0] == 0, 
     s'[0] == 1, u'[0] == -0.1}, {u, s}, {t, 0, 10}]];

Plot[Evaluate[{s[t], u[t]} /. solution],
 {t, 0, 10},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{s[t], u[t]}, {0.85, 0.55}]]
```

[image]